# How to find image pattern from a rectangle?

Tags: javafx

Okay, so a similar kind of question was asked here about finding color from a rectangle using this code (in an if statement, we would get a boolean):

```
    Rectangle.getfill.equals(Color.BLACK).
```

Now, in my project I have filled my rectangles with images. Is there a way to find what image I put in my rectangle as similar to the code above finding what color was put on it.

```
    if (((Rectangle) object).getFill().equals("C:\\Users\\shree\\IdeaProjects\\DOLP2\\src\\sample\\00.jpg"))
    {
        System.out.println("Image detected");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Not working");
    }
```

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: If you need a `Rectangle` with special features consider extending it.

Comment: I don't need a rectangle with special features. But, thank you for your advice! It could come in handy in later projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an Image pattern like you added to the image the reason yours isnt working is its comparing a filePath String to the fill of a rectangle which will never be equal but if you turn that filePath into an ImagePattern you've got yourself some Image detection. Check out my example.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    //This is the Important part
    private ImagePattern imagePattern = new ImagePattern(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("FilePath.png")));

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();

        rectangle.setX(150.0f);
        rectangle.setY(75.0f);
        rectangle.setWidth(300.0f);
        rectangle.setHeight(150.0f);

        //Setting rectangle with the Image Pattern
        rectangle.setFill(imagePattern);

        Button button = new Button("Check");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            if(rectangle.getFill().equals(imagePattern))
                System.out.println("We've got it Captain!!");
            else
                System.out.println("new fone who dis");
        });

        VBox vBox = new VBox(rectangle);
        vBox.getChildren().add(button);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

You bet every time you click that button it prints out:

> We've got it Captain!!

Comment: Just as a side note. From the Oracle documentation for the [java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) command: _The java command can be used to launch a JavaFX application by loading a class that ... extends_ `javafx.application.Application` In other words, method `main()` is not required.

Comment: @Abra I had no idea

Comment: @Matt Bro, you are the man! This will help me a lot in my project! Thank you!

Comment: @ShreemanGautam If this answer satisfies the question can you accept the answer(By clicking the checkmark next to it) so that others don't think the question is unresolved

Comment: @Matt Just did it.